# Draw Line and fill with UIVisualEffectView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uivisualeffectview

So the drawing lines part is setup:

```
func drawLineFrom(_ fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint) {

        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(tempImageView.frame.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        tempImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tempImageView.frame.size.width, height: tempImageView.frame.size.height), blendMode: .normal, alpha: 1.0)

        context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: fromPoint.x, y: fromPoint.y))
        context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: toPoint.x, y: toPoint.y))

        context?.setLineCap(.round)
        context?.setLineWidth(brushWidth)
        context?.setStrokeColor(blurEffectView(effect: blurEffect))
        context?.setBlendMode(.normal)

        context!.strokePath()

        var img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        tempImageView.image = img
        tempImageView.alpha = opacity

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    }
```

It is basically using touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded and this is where `fromPoint` and `toPoint` is coming from.

And like you can already see I'm trying to fill this line up with an UIVisualEffectView instead of a Color. Obviously my method doesn't really work. 
What would be the best solution to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Setup

A `UIVisualEffectView` doesn't really have any content by itself, rather it depends on the views below it. If you want to give the effect of drawing with a `UIVisualEffect` you should construct your view hierarchy that you want the impression of drawing on top of. Perhaps something like view with an image view, displaying some image, then an effect view on top of that, like:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image.jpg"))
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
let effectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
effectView.frame = imageView.bounds
let view = UIView(frame: imageView.bounds)
view.addSubview(imageView)
view.addSubview(effectView)
```

Then you'll need to snapshot the view hierarchy in this state. This will act like the view if it were completely filled in by the touches. You can do that by adding an extension on `UIView`:

```
extension UIView
{
    var snapshot: UIImage?
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, 0)
        self.drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

And

```
let image = view.snapshot!
```

We can now replace out `UIVisualEffectView` with an `UIImageView` holding our snapshotted view hierarchy:

```
effectView.removeFromSuperview()
let topImageView = UIImageView(image: image)
view.addSubview(topImageView)
```

You can then mask `topImageView` to drawing paths by declaring a `CAShapeLayer` property and setting it as the mask layer for `topImageView`

```
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
```

And

```
topImageView.layer.mask = shapeLayer
```

### Drawing

Now you can write your `drawLine` function:

```
func drawLine(from fromPoint: CGPoint, to toPoint: CGPoint)
{
    let path: UIBezierPath
    if let layerPath = self.shapeLayer.path
    {
        path = UIBezierPath(cgPath: layerPath)
    }
    else
    {
        path = UIBezierPath()
    }
    path.move(to: fromPoint)
    path.addLine(to: toPoint)
    self.shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    self.shapeLayer.lineWidth = brushWidth
    self.shapeLayer.lineCap = "round"
    self.shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
}
```

In a playground in the live view without calling `drawLine` my view looks like:

[image]

After calling:

```
drawLine(from: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), to: CGPoint(x: imageView.frame.maxX, y: imageView.frame.maxY))
drawLine(from: CGPoint(x: 0, y: imageView.frame.maxY), to: CGPoint(x: imageView.frame.maxX, y: 0))
```

It looks like:

[image]

You should be aware that this is processor intensive and may not be performant.

### Update

If you want to update the view hierarchy or visual effect later, you could keep the `UIVisualEffectView` in the view hierarchy rather than calling `removeFromSuperview` and just hide it. Then repeat the process of snapshotting and masking. For example:

```
func updateMask(with visualEffect: UIVisualEffect)
{
    topImageView.isHidden = true
    effectView.isHidden = false

    effectView.effect = visualEffect
    topImageView.image = view.snapshot

    topImageView.isHidden = false
    effectView.isHidden = true
}
```

You can see the code I used for my playground [here.](https://gist.github.com/bgayman/e02d148f0549b9cafb6ca11cffed0f8e)

Comment: Thank you very much this is very helpful! I will let you know when I have more questions.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without converting it to an UIImage? Because I still want to be able to change the blur style afterwards. But this is currently not possible because it is a UIImage.

Comment: The problem with applying the mask directly to the `UIVisualEffectView` is it doesn't blur because when you start the `UIVisualEffectView` is effectively hidden so the blur never renders even after you unhide those parts specified in your mask. If you want to update your view hierarchy or visual effect I would recommend just not removing the `UIVisualEffectView` from your view and instead just hide it and repeat the process I outlined. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Great answer! Very well explained.